# How can I paste Excel cells as an image with a hyperlink on the image?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I select and copy the cells `C4:I26` when I click on a button `copiar texto` and I paste them as an image. This is already happening.

I need this image to have a certain hyperlink when I paste it (on Outlook). So a click on the image opens this website.

```
Sub copiar_texto()
    Sheets("Planilha2").Select
    Range("C4:I26").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    Selection.Copy
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

    Sheets("Planilha1").Select
    Range("F34").Select

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 4")).Select

    Selection.OnAction = "copiar_texto"
    
    Range("H31").Select
    
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
End Sub
```

Comment: You may also want to read up on [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 2):

This will copy a range from Planilha2 to Planilha1 as a picture, and add a hyperlink to the copied shape.  If I copy that and paste it into an Outlook mail, it arrives with the hyperlink intact.

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim shp As Shape
    
    Sheets("Planilha2").Range("C4:I26").CopyPicture _
                Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    
    With Sheets("Planilha1")
        .Paste
        Set shp = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=shp, Address:="http://www.google.com"
    End With
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. I just have one question, sorry if it´s a silly one, I am really new at this. Do I replace my current code with this one? Or I just add it to it? Cause I need to copy these cells when I hit the button "copiar texto" that is on "Planilha1"

Comment: You would assign "Tester" to your existing button.